# bson 2.0.0.rc2 gem installing under windows cmd fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, cmd

I'm trying to use ruby+rails under windows cmd.exe, everything is now fine except bundle doesn't install one gem:

```
<...>
Using sass (3.2.11)
Using bootstrap-sass (2.3.1.3)
Using bootstrap-select-rails (1.3.0.1)
Installing bson (2.0.0.rc2)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

    C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
generating native-x64-mingw32.def
compiling native.c
native.c:17:23: fatal error: arpa/inet.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [native.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bson-
2.0.0.rc2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bson-2.0.0.rc2/ext/bso
n/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing bson (2.0.0.rc2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install bson -v '2.0.0.rc2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

What am I doing incorrect?